# Элемент не добавляется в другой элемент

Tags: javascript

Доброй ночи спящим и кодирующим, вот такая проблема вышла, я пытаюсь добавить картинку с действием в первый столбик таблицы, но добавляется она только в последнюю клеточку первого столбика, почему так? Листинг ниже

JS код (не ругайтесь, новичок)

```
function create_add_url() {
    for (const table_name in urls) {
        let need_urls = urls[table_name]
        let rows = document.getElementById(table_name).firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
        for (const element_index in need_urls){
            let icon = document.createElement('img')
            icon.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                document.location = need_urls[element_index]
            })
            icon.src = plus_path
            icon.style = 'align-self:center;cursor:pointer;'
            for (let row of Array.from(rows.rows).slice(1)) {
                // console.log(row.cells[+element_index + 1].firstElementChild.firstElementChild)
                row.cells[+element_index + 1].firstElementChild.firstElementChild.appendChild(icon)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML код:

```
<tr class="work_row" data-table-name="Rejuvenation">
                                    <td></td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <select name="Rejuvenation___tree_species___5" multiselect-search="true" required="" id="id_Rejuvenation___tree_species___1" multiple="" style="display: none;"><option value="1">Apple</option><option value="2">Orange</option></select><div class="multiselect-dropdown" style="width: 157px;"><div class="multiselect-dropdown-list-wrapper"><input class="multiselect-dropdown-search form-control" placeholder="Search" style="width: 100%; display: block;"><div class="multiselect-dropdown-list" style="height: 20rem;"><div><input type="checkbox"><label>Apple</label></div><div><input type="checkbox"><label>Orange</label></div></div></div><span class="placeholder">Choise option</span></div>
                                                <img src="/static/icons/plus.svg" style="align-self: center; cursor: pointer;"></div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="number" name="Rejuvenation___tree_height___5" step="any" required="" id="id_Rejuvenation___tree_height___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Rejuvenation___no_damage___5" id="id_Rejuvenation___no_damage___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Rejuvenation___damage_side_shoots___5" id="id_Rejuvenation___damage_side_shoots___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Rejuvenation___damage_terminal_shoots___5" id="id_Rejuvenation___damage_terminal_shoots___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Rejuvenation___damage_leaves___5" id="id_Rejuvenation___damage_leaves___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Rejuvenation___cause_browsing___5" id="id_Rejuvenation___cause_browsing___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Rejuvenation___cause_broken_off___5" id="id_Rejuvenation___cause_broken_off___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Rejuvenation___cause_fungi_infects___5" id="id_Rejuvenation___cause_fungi_infects___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Rejuvenation___cause_beetle___5" id="id_Rejuvenation___cause_beetle___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Rejuvenation___cause_peeling_damage___5" id="id_Rejuvenation___cause_peeling_damage___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Rejuvenation___other_skidding_trail___5" id="id_Rejuvenation___other_skidding_trail___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Rejuvenation___other_fork___5" id="id_Rejuvenation___other_fork___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input_field">
                                                <div class="input_value">
                                                    <input type="text" name="Rejuvenation___other_text___5" maxlength="250" required="" id="id_Rejuvenation___other_text___1">
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
```

Вот как это работает (на скрине 5 строк но это не важно, всегда картинка вставляется именно в последнюю клеточку столбца):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откуда привычка писать plus_path  , а не plusPath и зачем сложные названия, читать больно. И еще getElementById  есть не только у document

Comment: (const element_index in need_urls)  - 'эта строчка действительно получает  index? Вообще Замечание: for...in не следует использовать для Array, где важен порядок индексов.

Comment: По поводу написания, я пишу на питоне как на основном языке там не camelcase а snakecase, по поводу сложности названий(?) так пишу, не p и s же использовать, мне понятно уже лучше, но я выше написал что на js я новичок, а решения проблемы я так и не увидел кроме замечаний по поводу стиля кода.

Comment: ps - 'эта строчка действительно получает index?

Comment: Да, проблем с получением данных нет, консоль чистая, я после вашего требования проверил, и ссылки всё получает и всё ок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вы дали только часть разметки, мне трудно понять, что и как вы перебираете. Но скорее всего дело вот в чём: вы создаёте один элемент изображения и пытаетесь несколько раз вставить его в ячейки. При этом этот элемент не размножается, он просто последовательно переходит из ячейки в ячейку, пока не оказывается в последней. Вам нужно переместить создания элемента с привязкой обработчика внутрь цикла — то есть, сколько раз вам нужно вставить, столько раз и создавать новый элемент. Хотя вместо создания множества обработчиков для множества однотипных элементов лучше использовать [Делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation).

Comment: Там сам код еще очень сложно понять, что куда, много не понятно, почему перебор идет  in, а снизу  of тоже не ясно, много дуплетов firstElementChild, что бы это значило и как я понял, ему нужно добавлять картинку в ту ячейку, куда он нажал ну или произвел в той ячейки какое-то действие... Вообщем вы правы, по описанию мало что понятно, код тоже попробуй - прочитай. Вопрос необходимо улучить и дать пояснение к коду.

Comment: Да, вы оказались правы, решение в том что это один и тот же объект, то есть получается он через ссылку создан? Просто для меня как для бекэндера это тяжко понимать что в js ссылки а что конкретные переменные. Спасибо вам за ответ!

Comment: @antipups Да, с точки зрения языка, DOM-элемент это объект и вы после создания получаете на него ссылку и оперируете одним и тем же объектом, если намеренно его не клонировать, скажем, через [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). Но в вашем случае проще создавать новые элементы в цикле.

Comment: @antipups В JS противопоставляются не ссылки и переменные, а типы данных в переменных: есть примитивные данные, которые копируются, и есть разные типы объектов, которые всегда передаются по ссылке. См. подробнее [Копирование объектов и ссылки](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-copy) — вообще это очень хороший учебник по JS, стоит прочитать перед работой с языком, многие вопросы отпадут и будет ясное понимание, что вы делаете.